# Whatsapp-web.js Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serialize')

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I'm using whatsapp-web.js to troll my friend, spamming love messages, but when I try to send the message, I get the following error:

> throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
> ^
>
> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serialize')

My code:

```
const Client = require('whatsapp-web.js').Client;
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    console.log('Scan the following QR Code:');
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message_create', async msg => {
    if (!msg.fromMe) return;
    if (msg.body.startsWith('-love')) {
        console.log('Sending love messages ' + msg.to.replace('@g.us', ''))
        var chat = await msg.getChat()
        var args = msg.body.split(' ').slice(1)
        var sentMessage = 'I love you <3'
        var amount = Math.floor(args[0]) || 10
        for (let i = 0 ; i < amount ; i++) {
            chat.sendMessage(sentMessage)
            console.log('Sended Message')
        }
    }
})

client.initialize();
```

What I tried:

1. Modify the Injected.js in whatsapp-web.js folder
2. Disconnect my other devices
3. Send the message using chat-id

- Node version: 19.0.0
- Windows version: 21H2

I expected the command to send to my friend a specified in the command number of "I love you <3" messages

Comment: The error should be either syntax error or you didn't declare it correctly. Check your codes where you define "serialize".

Comment: @TitanXP It's not my code, its a node module called "whatsapp-web.js"